# White screen instead of google map displays on some android devices

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working on an app built using phonegap build which uses the google maps api (not plugin). The map has been working fine until recently where it shows as a blank white screen on some Android phones, mostly those running Android 9. There are no map controls showing, and the rest of the app works fine. A test device using Android 5.1.1 was working fine, as well as on iOS.

After debugging a phone with the issue, one error showed that 'google was not defined'.

In the index.html file, I tried moving the line that imports the google maps api script above the javascript that uses google maps, specifying the version of google maps to a previous one in case a recent change broke it somehow, and loading it using async and not but none of these made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because of Google Play's new requirement to include the target SDK version for the latest version of Android - in config.xml I had recently added:

`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />`

and google maps javascript was being pulled in with http rather than https - changed in index.html to:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXX&region=GB&libraries=places"></script>`

and this resolved the white screen showing on some Android devices.